# QTimer running sequentially with main instead of Parralel

Tags: multithreading, qt, qtimer

I've been setting up a test simulator for different student code. It needs to simulate the a robot's movement code intermittently during student code. So maybe ever 50 ms it will run a sensor function and a movement function(time to be optimized later) regardless of what is happening during the student code. I wrote a bunch of code that should create the proper threads etc but one code always ends up waiting for the other code. I then simplified only down to basics but whatever setup I use the code keeps running sequentially. My code and output is below in the simplest manner I could put it in.

The Timer Class:

```
Timer::Timer(int delayLength){
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),this, SLOT(MySlot()));
    qDebug() << "Timer Initialized";
    isTimerRunning = true;
    timer->start(delayLength);
}

void Timer::StopMovement(){
    stoppingMutex.lock();
    isTimerRunning = false;
    stoppingMutex.unlock();
}

void Timer::MySlot(){
    stoppingMutex.lock();
    if(isTimerRunning){
        qDebug() << "Timer Executed";
    }

    else{
        timer->stop();
    }
    stoppingMutex.unlock();
}
```

Main Class:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Timer mTimer(100);
    for(int i = 0; i<5;i++){
         QThread::sleep(1);
         qDebug()<< "Slept";
    }
    qDebug() << "Finished";
    return app.exec();
 }
```

I would like this code to print a lot of "Timer Executed" with intermittent instances of the message "slept" instead I get:

```
Timer Initialized
Slept
Slept
Slept
Slept
Slept
Finished
Timer Executed
Timer Executed
Timer Executed
Timer Executed
(...)
```

Comment: You don't show any threads being created. Unless your `Timer` class somehow creates threads in code you haven't shown, all of this is going to run in your application's main thread. And since you're blocking the main thread (with the `sleep` calls in `main`) the event loop is not running normally and the timer-expiration messages can't get delivered until it unblocks.

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression that QTimer was creating it's own thread. Thanks that should solve my problem.